# booting Android lenovo A6000+

Tags: boot-loop, ota-update

I am using lenovo A6000+ phone.

I have rooted it earlier with kingroot app, and recently there was system update, so I downloaded update and tried to install it but at the time of rebooting there were options for system recovery, first I choose to "install update from adb sideload" but that gave me an error. so I again restarted my phone and clean the cache, then again rebooted and chose adb sideload but there is nothing happening.

So I again rebooted and chose factory reset. But even after doing factory reset to my phone, it is still giving me options for system recovery.

How can I start my phone, can I install that update externally and start the phone and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the update fails because you have modified the system partition with your root. I don't know what you can do to revert these changes, but you can simply [install cyanogenmod on your phone](http://linuxhalwa.blogspot.co.at/2015/06/install-cyanogenmod-11-on-lenovo-a6000.html)

Comment: i have read the link u suggested but its not possible to power on the phone. so how am i supposed to install the cyanogen.

Comment: you said "there were options for system recovery". setup adb and fastboot on your pc ( http://www.droidguiding.com/a-very-simple-solution-to-install-adb-and-fastboot-on-your-pc-tutorial/) .then connect your phone to your pc, and while it is booting press a combination of your hardware buttons (until you get into fastboot mode). then if your device is in fastboot mode (check via `fastboot devices`) download this (https://www.dropbox.com/s/9h5btmtf2ejricq/twrp.img?dl=0) and run `fastboot flash recovery twrp.img` (where twrp.img is the path to the downloaded image). then reboot

Comment: then boot into the recovery, choose factory reset, reset also cache partition and dalvik cache, then download this (https://userscloud.com/eibfm2wwdfie), this (https://userscloud.com/w65n8qepmpgt) and this (http://gapps.itvends.com/gapps-kk-20140606-signed.zip), and put them onto your phone (in recovery `adb push .../gapps.zip /sdcard/` as example) and choose "install zip" on your phone, choose from internal storage (sdcard) and install first "ED300_CM11_Kick_Lenovo_A6000_K30-T.zip" then "ED300_CM11_Update_1-8-2015.zip" and last the gapps zip. happy flashing and bricking :)